# Changing TransformListener's transform

Tags: ros, transform-listener, stampedtransform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

So I'm trying to change the transform that I'm getting from a transform listener, but it doesn't seem to change.

When trying to set the values, they don't change. Here I'm declaring a const variable, since getRotation.getX returns a const:

```
const double scalarX = transform.getRotation().getX() + 0.1;
transform.getRotation().setX(scalarX);
```

Transform is acting like it's const, but it's not and so isn't getRotation, but I still can't change the values.

```
tf::StampedTransform transform;
listener.lookupTransform(*camera_depth, *base_link, ros::Time(0), transform);

cout << "Before added scalar: " << transform.getRotation().getX() << endl;

const double scalarX = transform.getRotation().getX() + 0.1;
transform.getRotation().setX(scalarX);
cout << "After added scalar: " << transform.getRotation().getX() << endl;
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205720/changing-transformlistener%27s-transform/) by [RosFan19](https://answers.ros.org/users/21450/rosfan19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 107 on 2015-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not operating as you expect because you are operating on a temporarily allocated Quaternion not on the transform object.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RosFan19](https://answers.ros.org/users/21450/rosfan19/) on 2015-03-27**:
You are correct. Thanks for the answer!